# SQL Issues when using docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, ubuntu, flask, sqlalchemy

I am attempting to get data from mssql

Everything works fine on windows, but the error only occurs when I dockerize the application.

I cut out a lot of code but I think this sums up what I'm attempting here. The server requires Driver 17. Any clues as to what the issue is?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11
MAINTAINER Name <email>
WORKDIR /code
EXPOSE 5000/tcp
RUN su
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN exit
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
RUN wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1w.tar.gz -O openssl-1.1.1w.tar.gz
RUN tar -zxvf openssl-1.1.1w.tar.gz
RUN cd openssl-1.1.1w && ./config && make && make install && ldconfig && openssl version
RUN cd ..
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]
```

docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '3.1'
services:
  <name>:
    image: redis:7-alpine
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
       SECRET_KEY: <loc>
    ports:
      - "<>f"
    command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning --requirepass SECRET_KEY
    networks:
      - <ntwrk>
    secrets:
      - <sec>
  <name>:
    build: ./client
    container_name: <name>
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:<>"
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
      - ./app/node_modules
    networks:
      - <ntwrk>
  flask_server:
    build: ./server
    container_name: flask_server
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
       SECRET_KEY: <key>
    ports:
      - "<>:<>"
    volumes:
      - ./server:/code
    networks:
      - <ntwrk>
    secrets:
      - <sec>

networks:
  <ntwrk>:
    driver: bridge

secrets:
  <sec>:
    file: <file>
```

models:

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from uuid import uuid4

db = SQLAlchemy()

def get_uuid():
    return uuid4().hex

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.String(32), primary_key=True, unique=True, default=get_uuid())
    email = db.Column(db.String(345), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
```

server routes

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, session, make_response, send_file
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_session import Session

from .config import ApplicationConfig
from ..auth.models import db, User

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True, origins=[<my-origin>], expose_headers=["Content-Disposition"])
app.config.from_object(ApplicationConfig)

bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
server_session = Session(app)
db.init_app(app)


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def login():
    if request.method == "OPTIONS":  # CORS preflight
        return _build_cors_preflight_response()

    email = request.json['email']
    password = request.json['password']

    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if user is None:
        return jsonify({"error": "Unauthorized"}), 401

    if not bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password):
        return jsonify({"error": "Unauthorized"}), 401

    session["user_id"] = user.id

    return jsonify({
        "id": user.id,
        "email": user.email
    })


def _build_cors_preflight_response():
    response = make_response()
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '<my-origin')
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization")
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
    return response
```

The following error occurs:

```
flask_server    | ERROR:defaults.core.server_routes.defaultRoutes:Exception on /login [POST]
flask_server    | Traceback (most recent call last):
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
flask_server    |     self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
flask_server    |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3292, in raw_connection
flask_server    |     return self.pool.connect()
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect
flask_server    |     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1269, in _checkout
flask_server    |     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
flask_server    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout
flask_server    |     rec = pool._do_get()
flask_server    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 169, in _do_get
flask_server    |     with util.safe_reraise():
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
flask_server    |     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 167, in _do_get
flask_server    |     return self._create_connection()
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
flask_server    |     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__
flask_server    |     self.__connect()
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 902, in __connect
flask_server    |     with util.safe_reraise():
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
flask_server    |     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 898, in __connect
flask_server    |     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
flask_server    |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 637, in connect
flask_server    |     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 616, in connect
flask_server    |     return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    | pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)')
flask_server    |
flask_server    | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
flask_server    |
flask_server    | Traceback (most recent call last):
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
flask_server    |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
flask_server    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
flask_server    |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
flask_server    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
flask_server    |     return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
flask_server    |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
flask_server    |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
flask_server    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
flask_server    |     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/code/defaults/core/server_routes/defaultRoutes.py", line 153, in login
flask_server    |     user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2748, in first
flask_server    |     return self.limit(1)._iter().first()  # type: ignore
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2847, in _iter
flask_server    |     result: Union[ScalarResult[_T], Result[_T]] = self.session.execute(
flask_server    |                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2308, in execute
flask_server    |     return self._execute_internal(
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2180, in _execute_internal
flask_server    |     conn = self._connection_for_bind(bind)
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2047, in _connection_for_bind
flask_server    |     return trans._connection_for_bind(engine, execution_options)
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "<string>", line 2, in _connection_for_bind
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 139, in _go
flask_server    |     ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
flask_server    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1143, in _connection_for_bind
flask_server    |     conn = bind.connect()
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3268, in connect
flask_server    |     return self._connection_cls(self)
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 147, in __init__
flask_server    |     Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2430, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
flask_server    |     raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
flask_server    |     self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
flask_server    |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3292, in raw_connection
flask_server    |     return self.pool.connect()
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect
flask_server    |     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1269, in _checkout
flask_server    |     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
flask_server    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout
flask_server    |     rec = pool._do_get()
flask_server    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 169, in _do_get
flask_server    |     with util.safe_reraise():
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
flask_server    |     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 167, in _do_get
flask_server    |     return self._create_connection()
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
flask_server    |     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__
flask_server    |     self.__connect()
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 902, in __connect
flask_server    |     with util.safe_reraise():
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
flask_server    |     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 898, in __connect
flask_server    |     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
flask_server    |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 637, in connect
flask_server    |     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 616, in connect
flask_server    |     return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
flask_server    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
flask_server    | sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)')
flask_server    | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

Comment: Seems familiar. Have you looked at [pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '\[08001\] \[Microsoft\]\[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server\]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)') #610](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/610) yet?

Comment: Aside... if you `docker run -it --rm -u 0 python:3.11 find / -name "*openssl*"` you might find that a version of OpenSSL is already installed. Trying to install OpenSSL 1.1.1w over the top of it might not work out well.

Comment: Where is the database actually running (it doesn't seem to be in your compose file)?  In your application's configuration, how are you telling it to connect to the database?

Comment: @DavidMaze The database is running independent of my code, it is connecting using my credentials, which works when run from my computer. The database is used by multiple programs so think of it more as a master database.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have read through there, but i couldn't find a working solution. I have been able to get it to work in other code by installing openssl 1.1.1p and 1.1.1w, it was required to get a previous application running. I think its a mistake in my code somewhere that im just overlooking rather than an issue with an install.

Comment: SQL Server 2016 and later have had TLS v1.2 protocol support out-of-the-box, and there have been service packs, cumulative updates and hotfixes applicable to SQL Server 2008 and later that enable TLS v1.2 protocol support and stronger encryption keys. Have you considered that instead of trying to downgrade OpenSSL (in such a "unique" and "interesting" way) to work with your old SQL Server instance that perhaps applying supported fixes to your server would be a better solution?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Why are the words "Unique" and "Interesting" in quotes like that? I am not the one who decides what we do with the server. If you perhaps have some other "genius" idea, let me know.